# Rendering Sound In Video Sequencer

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

How do you render sound with your video in the video sequencer? I already placed a sound strip with the video strip but how do you render the sound with the video?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47323/2843

Answer (score 2):

Good question Austin,

---the below answer is if you want to *render* a file which has audio embeded, not for if you are having trouble playing back an audio file in the Video Sequence Editor---

Once you have audio in the video sequence editor, you're halfway there.

So you need to change your render output settings in the render tab

[image: output]

Change it to a video format (I normally pick h264)

[image: h264]

Then change the wrapper format to *Quicktime MOV*, and the codec to *h264*  or *PNG* if you need lossless quality.

Below that, change the audio codec from none to *AAC* or *MP3* (they're the ones I have had most luck with)

[image: final]

And then hit render and it should be in the final render output file (a .mov)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that

- the audio strip has actually sound and you can hear it from your pc (sorry if it seems obvious)
- the audio strip is placed in frames that you are playing (and there is sound for those frames in the audio strip)
- the audio strip is not muted (H key - ALT-H to unmute)
- the audio is not disabled from playback (look in the timeline menu "playback" there is a switch
- there is not an audio level curve that sets the volume to zero (in the default video editing screen, see the upper left graph editor, after selecting that audio strip), in other words that the audio strip volume has not been animated (to zero)

What another answer says is not mandatory, afaik, unless you want to output a video (with sound): I have PNG output now and I can hear the sound while playing the video in the video editor...

Comment: What do you mean? A PNG output can not have synchronised audio, as it is just a sequence of images

Comment: Yes, it's true, and I know. Of course, if you need an _output file_ with video and audio, you need to render your output to a video _file_. 

But as the question asked, you should hear audio playing _"in the video sequencer"_ anyway, it doesn't matter which output file type you set in the rendering panel.

Just as an example, you could need to output a mute video file, created mixing two other video file (both with audio) in the sequencer, and need to use their sound as mixing reference. Maybe then you render just video to the mute file and then add another soundtrack to the mixed video.

Comment: Aaaah see I was interpreting  austin as asking how to render with sound, I think you are interpreting austin as asking how to play back video with sound in the video sequence editor.